# Book on coordinate transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, coordinate-systems, 3d, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book that covers various coordinate systems in 3 dimensions,  various methods of representing rotations and other transformations like rotation matrices and quarternions, including algorithms for conversions between various coordinate systems and representations of transformations. Is there a single book that covers these.

Comment: Many of the 1000+ page texts on "mathematical methods for physicists" for   graduate physics students will have this material in spades. If you have access to a mathematics (or physics, or engineering) university library, I recommend going there and flipping through the offerings on the shelves.

Comment: Probably the best example of the kind of book I'm talking about is Morse/Feshbach's 2-volume treatise **Methods of Theoretical Physics**. I believe this gives an extensive coverage of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know a book that covers all aspects.

- In mathematical introductions for physics and engineering you will find Cartesian, cylindrical and spherical coordinates mostly, because it will help to solve problems with cylindrical and spherical symmetry.
- Books on mechanical engineering or theoretical mechanics will introduce Euler angles for the modeling of rigid bodies. Note [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).
- Books on robotics often treat the modeling of a robotic arm and will provide useful representations for that application, including use of quaternions.
- Books on computer graphics will feature homogenous coordinates, to handle affine transforms in matrix representation. For general barycentric coordinates see e.g. [Barycentric coordinates](http://www.inf.usi.ch/hormann/barycentric/index.html)
- Books on geographical information systems or geodesy have to deal with the fact that the earth's surface is not flat and give useful coordinate systems and operations.
- Mathematical books on multidimensional calculus or differential geometry will teach you the general cases. 
  They build on analytical geomery and linear algebra.
- Books on aviation and space exploration might have their own specialities to handle navigation. E.g. see [ICRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Celestial_Reference_System).

Comment: But it does look to me that a lot of information on this topic is spread across different subjects and books. I was looking for a unified treatment of coordinate systems and representations of transformations and algorithms thereof.

Comment: It might exist. But my impression is that the principles are treated in books on calculus of several variables, which use the analytical geometry of linear algebra. And the applications are related to specific fields like computer graphics, mechatronics, GIS, books on relativity etc.